# Children's Christmas Movie where a magical store grants you one christmas present

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember a movie from my early childhood that had a somewhat interesting  premise. This would have been USA, and I would have seen it in the probably 2000-2005 range, but it could have been released earlier, anywhere in the 80's, 90's, or 00's.

The movie centered around a fantasy "magical" Christmas store that was only open for a limited time (one day probably, maybe longer.) The store didn't sell anything, but rather gave you a single chance to name any physical item and have it provided to you for free... your "perfect Christmas present." You could only get your present once, and once you did, you couldn't get more or anything else.

All I recall about the plot is a boy rushing back to the store as quickly as possible before it closed to try and change out the present he picked. If I recall, after the time is up (maybe once Christmas is over) the store magically disappears.